# Connection has already been closed - Spring .+ Hibernate 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am facing the following exception

"Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed" only on certain calls to the database. My service layer has spring with hibernate 4 and I am using the following configuration

```
class - org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean,
    hibernate.dialect - org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect,
    hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer - false,
    hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners - false,
    hibernate.connection.release_mode - auto,
    hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session - true,
    hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size - 1000, 
hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size - 1000
```

The exception mentioned above happens in certain calls like when I use hibernate's findById and when I try to do an insert/update operation. It doesn't look like a open connection issue as well as immediately after the failure when I invoke other services which fetch data from db, it works fine.

Please provide me some pointers and let me know if more information is required.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the piece of code where this exception happens? As well as any other relevant code

Comment: It depends how you are handling the sessions. Normally you should configure spring in order to keep one session per request. Is this a web application?